# rn-fetch-blob writeFile Error: Failed to create parent directory

Tags: android, react-native

[Unsupported path storage/emulated/0/test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65506841/unsupported-path-storage-emulated-0-test)

[Android APIv29 FileNotFoundException EACCES (Permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58430070/android-apiv29-filenotfoundexception-eacces-permission-denied)

https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/508

hello there,

In my application when user click on button that time an API call create a csv string and download it to directory

hear is my code working with emulator (android 8) and same code not working with my mobile (android 10)

```
           const pathToWrite = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir}/file.csv`;
          
           const csvString = data
            .map((item) => {
              return `${item.map((d) => d)}\n`;
            })
            .join('');

          console.log(csvString);
          RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(pathToWrite, csvString, 'utf8').then(() => {
            RNFetchBlob.android.addCompleteDownload({
              title: 'ebol.csv',
              description: 'Download complete',
              mime: 'application/scv',
              path: pathToWrite,
              showNotification: true,
            });

            console.log(`wrote file ${pathToWrite}`);
           
          });
```

i tried with static path

```
 const pathToWrite =
        'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package.name>/files/file.csv';
```

but still get error :

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 2):
> Error: Failed to create parent directory of 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package.name>/files/file.csv'
> promiseMethodWrapper@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2242:45
> writeFile@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:215561:42

Comment: Remove file:// from your static path.

Comment: @mitesh kalal Make sure you are checking read storage and write storage permissions before saving or downloading the file.

Comment: @Jigneshmayani yes I already grand read-write permission on my add

Comment: @blackapps it works for me, please can you answer it so I'll approve it.

Answer (score 0):

After reading many blogs I found that the error happens mostly using "DownloadDir" but not with others. As a needed to place my download files in "DownloadDir", **I tried adding a subfolder and it worked for me with RN 0.63.3 testing in android version <= 12**.

```
path: `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir}/anySubFolderName`
```